# How to Change the date format yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss to dd_mm_yy through modified java script value in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

How to Change the date format **yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss** to **dd_mm_yy** through *modified java script value* in pentaho?

Comment: Why Javascript step? you can use SELECT step to modify the format of a date.

Comment: ya i did that but searching for different ways...

Answer (score 3):

Use this function in `Modified Java Script Value` step:

```
date2str(input, "dd_MM_yy");
```

[image: kettle example]

Comment: yeah, @mzy you are awesome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **SELECT step**, and then in the Meta Data Tab, you can select the **datatype** as **DATE** and then use the format as **"dd_MM_yy"**

That's it, pretty simple :)

Answer (score 1):

In pentaho a Date has always the time. There is not such thing as only date.

So, my guess would be that you need to format on output, converting it to a string for example.

But, if what you need is the date without the time, and by this i mean "yyyy/mm/dd 00:00:00", you can get it like this in Javascript:

```
var dateFieldValue=<yourdatecolumn>;
var year = dateFieldValue.getYear()+1900;
var month = dateFieldValue.getMonth();
var day = dateFieldValue.getDate();
var dateOnly = new Date(year,month,day);
```

or the last line could be:

```
var dateOnly = year + '-' + (month+1) + '-' + day;
```

if you want a String output like 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Hope this helps.